# ComboBox SelectedValueChanged not recognizing value didn't change

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a Windows Forms Application. I have a ComboBox with a DropDownStyle of DropDownList. I also have a ListBox that is populated first on form load and then based on what is chosen is the ComboBox mentioned previously using the ComboBox's SelectedValueChanged event. The problem I am having is that if I choose the same item in the ComboBox twice in a row, the items in the ListBox are changing. The desired result is that the items in the ListBox stay the same in this situation. How might I fix this?

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off

Public Class frmGameScreen

    Private Sub btnQuit_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnQuit.Click

        Me.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub frmGameScreen_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim intAstrometricProbes As Integer
        Dim intCasesOfMedicalSupplies As Integer
        Dim intCommunicationsArrays As Integer
        Dim intProvisions As Integer
        Dim intSelfSealingStemBolts As Integer
        Dim intShieldGenerators As Integer
        Dim intWarpCoils As Integer

        cboPlanets.SelectedItem = "Ferenginar"
        lblItemPrice.Text = ""

        PopulateItemList()

    End Sub

    Private Sub lstItems_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles lstItems.SelectedValueChanged

        'lblItemPrice.Text = lstItems.Text
        lblItemPrice.Text = CStr(cboPlanets.SelectedIndex)

    End Sub

    Private Sub cboPlanets_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboPlanets.SelectedValueChanged

        PopulateItemList()

    End Sub

    Sub PopulateItemList()

        Dim rndRandomNum As New Random
        Dim intDisplay As Integer

        lstItems.Items.Clear()

        intDisplay = rndRandomNum.Next(1, 11)
        If intDisplay > 5 Then
            lstItems.Items.Add("Astrometric Probes")
        End If

        intDisplay = rndRandomNum.Next(1, 11)
        If intDisplay > 5 Then
            lstItems.Items.Add("Cases of Medical Supplies")
        End If

        intDisplay = rndRandomNum.Next(1, 11)
        If intDisplay > 5 Then
            lstItems.Items.Add("Communications Arrays")
        End If

        intDisplay = rndRandomNum.Next(1, 11)
        If intDisplay > 5 Then
            lstItems.Items.Add("Provisions")
        End If

        intDisplay = rndRandomNum.Next(1, 11)
        If intDisplay > 5 Then
            lstItems.Items.Add("Self-Sealing Stem Bolts")
        End If

        intDisplay = rndRandomNum.Next(1, 11)
        If intDisplay > 5 Then
            lstItems.Items.Add("Shield Generators")
        End If

        intDisplay = rndRandomNum.Next(1, 11)
        If intDisplay > 5 Then
            lstItems.Items.Add("Warp Coils")
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the current value in the combobox and don't recall the PopulateItemList if the value is the same

```
Private Sub cboPlanets_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, ......

    Dim idx As Integer = cboPlanets.SelectedIndex
    if idx <> currentItemIndex Then
         currentItemIndex = idx
         PopulateItemList() 
    End If
End Sub
```

where currentItemIndex is  declared at the global form level as

```
Dim currentItemIndex as Integer = -1
```